# React router base url not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've got this piece of code as a router for my React 15.0.1 universal app. React router version is 2.3.0.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Redirect, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';

import MainLayout from './../views/layout/mainLayout.jsx';
import Home from './../views/home.jsx';
import About from './../views/about.jsx';

import Error404 from './../views/404.jsx';

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: '/example-url'
});

module.exports = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={MainLayout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='about/' component={About} />
      <Route path='*' component={Error404} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

The problem is, that I'm getting the following error:

**Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM**

It seems that this solution doesn't work for my server side routing, as I'm trying to set a basename for my routes.

If I forget about the basename, then everything is fine but my application doesn't behave like a spa (I believe that routes on client side are not found).

Here is some of my server side entry point (app.js):

```
import routes from './client/routers/routes.jsx';

const engine = ReactEngine.server.create({
  routes: routes,
  routesFilePath: path.join(__dirname, 'client/routers/routes.jsx'),
});

app.engine('.jsx', engine);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/client/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.set('view', ReactEngine.expressView);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render(req.url, { metadata: res.data.metadata,baseUrl: res.data.baseUrl, url: res.data.url });  
});
```

Could anybody help please? I have read through the docs and supposedly this is the right way to do it and many people seem to support the solution but I'm stuck here.

Thank you very much

Comment: I wanted to clarify: The error is thrown by gulp, so it happens at bundling time so to say.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. I'm sure a lot of people must be going through the same issue...

Comment: The problem could have something to do with the fact that I'm using Paypal's react-engine to render my views from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

what's your history version?
if your react-router version is v2/v3, history version should be v3, v4 is for react-router v4